# What is the magazine advert on Dennis Nedry's desk

Tags: object-identification, jurassic-park, advertisements

I wondered if someone may help me to identify the advert of the open magazine on Nedry's desktop in *Jurassic Park*. It looks like a computer advert with purple 3D mesh and some graphs. It's possible to see a pyramidal logo brand but I'm not able to recognize it.

[image: Dennis Nedry's magazine showing a neon pink grid landscape on a black background with white text]

Comment: Not an answer, but the device at the top of the shot is a Motorola Envoy.  I worked on that for a couple of years, but they canceled the product just after we went into production.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis - It is indeed- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/270572/whats-the-little-black-box-on-nedrys-desk-in-jurassic-park/270573#270573. In fact it's the original prototype

Comment: I don’t think that's a magazine.  It's more likely to be a glossy product datasheet or brochure.

Answer (score 11):

The brand(s) on the uppermost advert belongs to [Miles Laboratories](https://www.hobbydb.com/marketplaces/hobbydb/subjects/miles-laboratories-company?filters%5Brelated_to%5D=15151&filters%5Bin_collection%5D=all&filters%5Bin_wishlist%5D=all&filters%5Bon_sale%5D=all&id=15151&order%5Bname%5D=name&order%5Bsort%5D=asc&page=3&subject_id=15151&subvariants=true). The company made, amongst other things, [tissue-typing equipment](https://www.labx.com/item/miles-scientific-sakura-tissue-tek-vip-3000-benchtop/LV41722539) (for use in medical and genetic testing) and was still using that logo up to 1992.

You can see both the colour and black-and-white variant of their logo on the ad.

[image: "MILES" with blue triple triangle logo and black version underneath]